# How to ensure a string has a substring exactly n times?

Tags: java, junit, tdd, assertj

I want to check whether a String contains a certain substring n times. I know I can do:

`Assertions.assertThat(myString).contains("xyz");`

Or even
`Assertions.assertThat(myString).containsOnlyOnce("xyz");`

But how can I ensure this for n times?

I tried something like:

`Assertions.assertThat(myString).areExactly(n, myString.contains("xyz"));` but sadly this is not compilable.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is tricky btw. What about `assertThat("aaa").areExactly(2, "aa")`? Is this true?

Comment: @Tunaki No, that does not even compile

Comment: @JoelCostigliola I know it doesn't compile. The point was not about making that compile but what it should return. Is `"aa"` present 2 or 1 time in `"aaa"`? That's why I said it was tricky.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are probably looking for [StringUtils.countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

> Counts the number of occurrences of one String in another

Comment: And another library... *sighs* No aspectj/junit solution alone?

Comment: @Kayaman I think he was actually referring to `assertj` library (the library he used to test assertions), not `aspectj`. :-) And from this point of view (and looking at how many different assertions `assertj` already implements), it would be convinient to have `containsTimes(int n, String expected)` in addition to `containsOnlyOnce(String expected)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can have the regex like this which test String  "myString" has SubString "xyz" n times.

```
Assertions.assertThat(myString).containsPattern("(xyz.*?){n}");
```

You can replace n with the count of substring you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

The AssertJ way would be to use a [Condition](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html) but it requires a little bit of work to implement it so I would use StringUtils.countMatches as Rahul Tripathi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Hamcrest has matchers for regex. You could do

`assertThat(actual, matchesPattern("(mystring.*?){2}))`

Which will test that `mystring` is shown up exactly twice

http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/org/hamcrest/text/MatchesPattern.html

and yes, another library, but for assertions this should be the only one you need. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
        String testString = "XXwwYYwwLOK";
        int count = 0;
        while (testString.contains("ww")) {
            count++;
            int index = testString.indexOf("ww");
            if(index + 1 == testString.length()){
                break;
            }
            testString = testString.substring(index + 1);
        }
```

I didn't test this code but it should work.

Comment: Good for you for contributing, but in this case this doesn't answer the question as the OP is asking about doing this within a unit test, ideally with a matcher.  Besides that, it's best not to post code you didn't run.